# Stylus, refer to variable name and value

Tags: stylus

### I want...

I am trying to do a loop like this

```
my-red = #fcc
my-blue = #ccf

for color in my-red, my-blue
  .{color}
    color x
```

I want it to output

```
.my-blue {
  color: #ccf;
}
.my-red {
  color: #fcc;
}
```

I can't seem to get both the variable name, and value as required

### I have tried...

```
my-blue = #ccf
my-red = #fcc

for x in 'my-blue' my-red
  .{x}
    color x
```

But I just get either the class name or color name (depending on if I use a string as the variable name to iterate)

```
.my-blue {
  color: "my-blue";
}
. {
  color: #fcc;
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use array for such task, so you can do this:

```
my-colors = my-red  #fcc,
            my-blue #ccf

for pair in my-colors
  .{pair[0]}
    color pair[1]
```

Doing so you declare the `my-colors` array and then iterate through it, using the first elements in the pairs as the names and second as the value.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't seem to get it to work on the stylus test page: http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/try.html

Comment: This test page have somewhat old version of stylus, it doesn't allow multiline variable declaration. So just replace the first lines of my snippet to `my-colors = my-red  #fcc, my-blue #ccf` and you'll see it would work. And the actual master branch (or the current version in npm) should render this perfectly without any changes.

Comment: it worked! big thanks for figuring this out a long time after I asked the question.